# Running a R script from rterm and eclipse gives an out of memory error

Tags: memory, r, rterm, statet

When I run a R script from eclipse statET, I get an out of memory error. However, I have no problem running the script in a console. Is it because the Eclipse puts a memory limit layer on top of the R process? If so, would other R GUIs have the same problem, say RStudio/JGR?

**EDIT**: per gsk3 suggestions

- 32 bit windows-xp with R 2.12.1.
- memory.limit  = 2048.

My question is whether Rterm is better than other GUIs in terms of memory usage, not how to solve the out of memory problem.

Comment: Some information about your system (which OS? how much memory? 32-bit or 64-bit OS? which R version?) and your data problem (how big is your data? what kind of analysis are you running?) would help answer this.  The answer is potentially very different if you're manipulating a tiny dataset on a system with a lot of memory vs. a huge dataset on a system with very little memory (or 32-bit OS architecture, in which case you might be running up against single-process memory limits).

Answer (score 2):

On my 4GB machine 64bit windows 7, eclipse with takes up 250-300MB + the R server java process 100MB.

If I run just Rgui its only 25MB.  So you could be running into machine memory limits with eclipse versus just R.

Also eclipse can run two ways, interactive server mode and terminal mode, I think terminal mode uses less memory.